# Como inverter os valores de uma coluna em um DataFrame no R?

Tags: r

Por exemplo, a coluna no meu Data Frame tem valores de 1 a 7; eu quero substituir 1 por 7, 2 por 6, 3 por 5, e assim por diante. Como fazer isto no R?

variável = 1,2,2,4,3,6,7
resultado desejado = 7,6,6,4,5,2,1

Comment: Você pode utilizar a função `rev()`

`c<-data.frame((rev(x)),y)`

Comment: Isso não é `8 - x`, onde `x` é o vetor a modificar?

Comment: `x <- c(1,2,2,4,3,6,7);y <- c(7,6,6,4,5,2,1);identical(y, 8 - x)`.

Comment: Coletei dados junto a um grupo de respondentes, a pergunta era: o quanto você se interessa pelo programa de televisão x. Os respondentes tinham de indicar o seu interesse em uma escala de 7 pontos. No meu data.frame há uma coluna cujo o título é "interesse" que contem as respostas de 1 a 7 de 73 respondentes. Eu quero saber como inverter esses valores da coluna do data.frame, ou seja, onde há 1 o valor será alterado para 7, onde há 2 será alterado para 6, onde há 3 o valor será alterado para 5, e assim por diante.